# What does it mean to encrypt from a key to a key?

Tags: public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to understand the key exchange happening with CurveMQ described here.

http://curvezmq.org/page:read-the-docs

My understanding of public key cryptography is you use a public key to encrypt data that can then be decrypted by the corresponding private key.  In the CurveMQ specification it describes encrypting data from a key to a key.  See the excerpts below they reference 2 keys.  What does this mean in layman's terms?

> The signature box (80 octets). This SHALL contain 64 zero octets,
> encrypted from the client's transient key C' to the server's permanent
> key S.

and

> A welcome box (144 octets) that encrypts the server public transient
> key S' (32 octets) and the server cookie (96 octets), from the server
> permanent key S to the client's transient key C'.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or see the section "General Design" near the bottom of the linked page. This is a Diffie-Hellman type key agreement using Bernstein et al's original 'curve25519' which was later renamed for clarity X25519 (because it uses Montgomery-form X-only formulas). DH derives a shared symmetric key from a sender keypair and a receiver keypair which these authors label 'from' and 'to'.

Comment: Looking at DH helped, thanks for the comment.